# Удалять точку в конце абзаца, если она попадётся

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте новостей всегда есть краткое описание из одного предложения, в конце которого договорились не ставить точку. Но редакторы сайта иногда забывают и ставят. Нужно средствами javascript или jquery  проверять и удалять точку, если поставили.

Вёрстка такая

```html
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка с точкой.</p>
</div>
...
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка без точки</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(".news_excerpt p").each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  if (text.length && text[text.length - 1] == ".") {
    text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
    $(this).text(text);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка с точкой.</p>
</div>
...
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка без точки</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы удалять точку, если поставили, можно использовать регулярные выражения. Например так:

```js
$(".news_excerpt p").each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text().replace(/\.$/, '');
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка с точкой.</p>
</div>
...
<div class="news_excerpt">
 <p>Выдержка без точки</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `.each` не нужен, [`text` может принимать функцию](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function): `$(".news_excerpt p").text((i,oldText)=>oldText.replace(/\.$/, ''))`